# To check Convergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do i check convergence of series whoose general term is given by $(\frac {n}{n+1})^{n}$.

I have tried ratio and root tests but they don't furnish any results.

Thanks

Comment: @Arcane1729 Isn't that $e$ ?

Comment: yes. I misread-  I didnt see you said series and not sequence- sorry

Comment: You can easily show that the general term converges to $e^{-1}$. In particular, not to $0$ -- the series cannot converge.

Comment: @ClementC. Which test?

Comment: No test with a name -- just [the fact that a necessary condition for a series to converge is that its general term be convergent to 0.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Limit_of_the_summand)

Comment: @ClementC. But is it suffcient? Anyways which test should i use

Comment: That one! It's a theorem: if a series is convergent, then its general term converges to zero. Here, your general term does not converge to zero: so the series must be divergent.

Comment: @ClementC. Thanks.I see you have used contraposition

Answer (score 0):

Use contrapositive of

> If $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$

in other words,

> If $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n\ne0$, then $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ diverges.

Comment: How to integrate

Comment: @Taylor, Sorry, it doesn't work that easy, I realised it today morning, forgot to correct it. When I was writing, I had it processed it the otherway: since its divergent, integral should diverge (and it should, confirms [alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+1+to+infinity+%28n%2F%28n%2B1%29%29^n) )